# What is the purpose of an extra file for translation?

Tags: theme-development, translation, localization

What code is required to put in `functions.php` in order to make the theme translation ready?

The TwentyEleven theme has only following line:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'twentyeleven', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

But in many tutorials they have mentioned to add following:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'twentyeleven', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
$locale = get_locale();
    $locale_file = TEMPLATEPATH . "/languages/$locale.php";
    if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) )
        require_once( $locale_file );
```

Is the second part required to add in the `functions.php` file to make it translation ready? If it is, why the TwentyEleven theme does not have it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second part is not required, it just loads a PHP file with language specific functions.

### Examples

- In some countries/regions/religions it is not allowed to use capital letters in a word for anything else than the name of some god. In these cases you probably want to remove the [*Wordpress to WordPress* filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13583).
- Some languages (Chinese) do not use spaces (in a predictable manner). If you use a function to set the excerpt length by *words* you will probably fail. In a language specific file you can disable that excerpt filter.
- Different languages need different amounts of space, vertically and horizontally. See the very helpful article [Text size in translation](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/article-text-size.en).
  The English word *views* is three times as long in Italian: *visualizzazioni*. That’s one of the reasons to test your layout not just in an extremely compact language like English. Thai for example takes more vertical space – you may have to adjust a grid layout with some extra rules (think `<input size>` and CSS of course).

Comment: I'll have to make a compilation of *all* your language related Answers :) & +1+ for the lovely display of atheism..!