# Add whitespace between Chinese and other letters

Tags: filters, the-content, encoding

I want to add a space between a Chinese character and a letter or a number to make the article more readable.

For example:

> Google与Apple展开的专利大战在2天之前结束。
>
> Google 与 Apple 展开的专利大战在 2 天之前结束。

But add the space manually is a hard work. How can I do it automatically? Maybe with CSS?

Comment: Wow, a heck of a Question! Would be nice if you added related resources that you found while researching for this problem. ::: *I only know of [one person](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1306/12615) who can answer this.* ::: And it would not be CSS (maybe impossible?), but WP/PHP...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question. This could be a useful part of a [specific language file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58401/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-extra-file-for-translation/58402#58402). It cannot be done in CSS, because CSS is (mostly) character agnostic. But using a filter and PHP it *is* possible and on topic:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 't5_chinese_spacing' );

function t5_chinese_spacing( $content )
{
    return preg_replace(
        '~([^\p{Han}]*)(\p{Han}+)([^\p{Han}])~imUxu',
        '\1 \2 \3',
        $content
    );
}
```

Be aware your internal encoding has to be UTF-8 to make that work. While WordPress works with other encodings too, [PHP needs UTF-8](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) for this. Read [WordPress Database Charset and Collation Configuration](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/wordpress-database-charset-and-collation-configuration/) to make sure everything is set up properly.

Also note I am using PHP’s character class for [Han unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification) here. This is not perfect, some punctuation marks Chinese writers might use are not included.